# How to fix ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR returned by Azure CDN?

Tags: azure-cdn

We recently started using Azure CDN however some users reported an issue and we got a screenshot from one of them:

[image]:

We were not able to get any more information on the issue. Any idea what could cause this and how to fix it?

Our origin server returns correctly the file with the following response headers:

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.google.com
Cache-Control: max-age=31536000
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 1956119
Content-Type: text/css
Date: Tue, 16 Feb 2021 18:44:10 GMT
ETag: "011889dd7ffd61:0"
Expect-CT: max-age=604800, enforce,
Feature-Policy: autoplay 'none'; camera 'none'
Last-Modified: Wed, 10 Feb 2021 18:07:38 GMT
strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar problem. I was able to fix this by enabling cache i Dev Tools.
[Enable cahce in Dev Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7fB5.png)